# JavaScript: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This javascript produces an error:

> missing ) after argument list

In firebug with the code:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function add( answer )
{   
  $.post('../page.php?cmd=view&id=3523', 
    {user_id: 3523, other_user_id: 2343}, function(d)
      $(answer).after(\"<span>Done!</span>\").remove();
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

function `d` misses an opening bracket, `{`

`$(answer).after(` should not be escaped `\"`, just a regular quote will do `"`

Comment: I knew it was something simple, Im just too noob:) Thanks for your help!

Comment: since you're using firebug; when you encounter things like this, you can always paste the code into the firebug console and reproduce the error, and from there, if you don't find the syntax error, you can try and remove things, bit by bit, and see what removed line causes the error to go away.

Answer (score 4):

Close `post()` function. third string from bottom should be `)`, not `}`.

**EDIT**: sorry, should be like this:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function add( answer )
{   
    $.post('../page.php?cmd=view&id=3523', {user_id: 3523, other_user_id: 2343}, function(d) {
        $(answer).after(\"<span>Done!</span>\").remove();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you escaping quotes? The problem is here :

```
$(answer).after(\"<span>Done!</span>\").remove();
```

change to

```
$(answer).after("<span>Done!</span>").remove();
```

or

```
$(answer).after('<span>Done!</span>').remove();
```

Also, you're missing a { after the post() function (probably you missed the right spot, since there's another in the wrong place), so the final output :

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function add( answer )
{   
$.post('../page.php?cmd=view&id=3523', {user_id: 3523, other_user_id: 2343}, function(d) {
            $(answer).after("<span>Done!</span>").remove();
        });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function add( answer )
{   
$.post('../page.php?cmd=view&id=3523', 
       {user_id: 3523, other_user_id: 2343}, 
       function(d){
         $(answer).after("<span>Done!</span>").remove()
       });
};
```